# Unable to update a column in a table on register

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am trying to teach myself asp.net.mvc and I started a project using the default template for MVC.
I changed the template a little, so when a register with the default action method I add the newly registered user id in another table called `companies`.

Basically, I added a new text field in the front end. When a user registers he types a number there. In the backend I look for a company from the `companies` table, which ID matches the number from the fronted. If there is a match I want to save the current user ID to a column in the companies table called CAId

Here is the whole action method (i made my modifications after the `await`):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterCA(RegisterCAEViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var currentUser = UserManager.FindByName(user.UserName);

            var roleresult = UserManager.AddToRole(currentUser.Id, "CompanyAdministrator");


            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

            var company = db.Companies.Find(model.CompanyCode);
            // find the company by the id passed in the frontend.
            if (company!=null)
            {
                company.CAId = currentUser.Id;
                //set the id
                db.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Here is what I tried in the method above :

```
                    var company = db.Companies.Find(model.CompanyCode);
                    // find the company by the id passed in the frontend.
                    if (company!=null)
                    {
                    company.CAId = currentUser.Id;
                    //set the id
                    db.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
```

When I register a user I do not get any errors. The user is registered, but the `CAId` field is not updated with the newly registered user ID.

Please, can somebody help and explain! I will be very grateful as I've been stuck with this for hours :(.

Comment: The `Find` method already returns a tracked entity, you should not have to modify its state. If you do not modify its state, what state is it in just before `SaveChanges`?

Comment: Not sure i understand the question, but the default state for CAId is null.

Comment: Nevermind, I think @michael berezin is right.

Comment: ok, so what is the state of `company` after you set `CAId` property, but without manually setting it to `Modified`? By state I mean added, modifed, unchanged, etc.

Comment: {companyId = 1, CAId = "identity string"}

Comment: No, what is the value of `db.Entry(company).State`?

Comment: that will sound lame, but i don't know how to determine this. i am a beginner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132239/discussion-between-crowcoder-and-robert-ross).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For anyone who will look for an answer to a similar question in future** - the code in my question works absolutely fine. The problem was that in the view I was using the default Register action method and not the modified above! Thanks to all the people, who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this line :
company.CAId = currentUser.Id;
After the line 
db.SaveChanges();
The the currentauser id is an identity column it will be set only after it was saved to the db.

Comment: i tried this and it didn't work. I believe currentUser.Id is set before my part of the code if i understood you correctly.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. `currentuser` is an existing entity. It's NOT created. And how would `company.CAId` be saved?

Comment: well, you may need to use the result variable to get the id (if it an identity column its usually returned after a create action) 
 (var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);)

Comment: `result` doesn't contain an `id`.

Comment: What does it contain?

Comment: It is an `IdentityResult`. My main point is, suggestions to try something don't belong in an answer, but in comments. Same for guesses, as in the other answer.

Answer (score -1):

my guess, you need to attach your entity to the context underlying the set.
dbSet.Attach(company)

and then
context.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();

Comment: try when retrieving record use AsNoTracking. For example dbSet.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(expression)
and when updating attach entity to context

Comment: Doesn't make sense. `db.Companies.Find` attaches the company. And first getting it with `AsNotracking` is useless.